# How do I programmatically set a user as spam in BuddyPress?

Tags: php, plugin-development, buddypress, spam

I am working on a moderation tool. One of the actions I want my moderators to be able to achieve is setting a user account as spam. I know how to do so via the UI as admin but how do I do the same via code?